# Difference in the sum of the output of pacsysclean vs. expac using awk?

Tags: pacman

I'm trying to see if I can learn something more about disk usage on my setup - with respect to installed packages(all). So I'm looking at the Arch [*Pacman Tips*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_tips#Listing_installed_packages_with_size) about *maintenance*. First I try :

```
expac -HM -s "%-30n %m" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'
3785.87 (Mb)
```

I know this is about right. Then I try:

```
pacsysclean | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
151634
```

Both commands before the pipe operator with `wc -l` yield the same number of packages. What is that number output by `pacsysclean`? Did I misuse `awk` in any way here? I've tried an optional assignment before the command i.e. `LC_ALL="C" command` to make sure it wasn't related to my *locale*. Result is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you haven't misused awk; it is more a case of (slightly) misusing `pacsysclean`.

`expac` is explicitly designed for extracting and parsing [alpm data](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/libalpm.3.html): the results you are seeing from it are accurate.

`pacsysclean` is not really inteded to be parseable, it simply sorts packages by their installed size. As a result, the unit size changes between MiB and KiB once the package size passes that threshold, consequently `awk` sums the column of integers indiscriminately.

Stick with `expac` for parsing and `pacsysclean` for a quick sort.

Comment: Units, thank you! I had scrolled but was really focused on the numbers, and lines.

Comment: @Amphiteóth It's pretty rare for anyone to scroll that far back through `pacsysclean` output: most just focus on the heavy end... :)